# How to author and manage very long regex patterns and reuse pattern blocks?

Tags: regex

Is there any proven way to overcome the difficulty of authoring and managing large regex patterns in your code? Preferably in a visual tool? Is there any way to build up a pattern from smaller reusable pieces? I could not find an web based regex visualizers that supported multine regex for instance.

We are currently using a technique to split patterns and store the pieces in variables, but this mixes languages - an architectural no-no for us - and also hinders the ability to paste the pattern into a visualizer.

I am using .NET/Powershell/JavaScript - but I am interested in the flavor agnostic perspective as well.

Comment: .NET / Powershell  and JavaScript - but the question is in general...

Comment: This doesn't fall into the web interface category, but I think you should check out Grok. It allows you to name a regex like `\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}` "SSN-STD" and then re-use that without re-writing the regex over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At my old job we used regex for everything. The best tools I found where the below:

Best regex editor in my opinion (it explains each segment and has a reference sheet): http://regex101.com

Best web multi-line regex editor:http://regexpal.com/

Best regex editor overall (a download for the price of $40): http://www.regexbuddy.com/

As far as managing regexs, we used to keep all regexs in a properties file separate from the code, where the code loads the property (regex) in real time. We also shared regexbuddy files for exchanging regex patterns. There was one file that was saved on source control that had lines and lines of simple patterns for matching certain things. It helped to create larger ones, using the smaller pieces. However, what I have learned is that basically all regexs need to be tweaked for your specific purposes. It is not as simple as piecing small ones together. The small ones just help get started in the right direction.

Comment: I would also suggest http://www.regexr.com/ - it does live matching, global and multiline matching flags and the like. Overall the usability has been far better than most others that I've used.

Answer (score 1):

Over here in flavor agnostic land, I sometimes do something like this (actual working code I just happened to be revisiting):

```
street = "(#{names}[A-Za-z0-9']+)((?:\\s+(?:#{StreetType.regexp}))?)"

space = '[\s.,]+'

at_a_street =
  '(?:and|&amp;|&amp;amp;|at|@|by|just\s+\w+\s+of|just\s+past|looking(?:\s+\w+)?\s+(?:at|to|towards?)|near)' +
    "#{space}#{street}"
between_streets =
  "(?:between|(?:betw?|btwn)\\.?)#{space}#{street}#{space}(?:and|&amp;|&amp;amp;)#{space}#{street}"
address = '(\b\d+)(?:\s*-\s*\d+|[a-z])?\s+' + street

@regexps = [
  /#{street}#{space}#{at_a_street}/i,
  /#{street}#{space}#{between_streets}/i,
  /#{address}/i,
  /#{address}#{space}#{at_a_street}/i,
  /#{address}#{space}#{between_streets}/i
]
```

Namely break the regexp up into meaningful bits, give them comprehensible names, and concatenate them as necessary. (You need to think a little extra about whether each bit can be safely concatenated with others, e.g. watch out for greedy expressions at the end.)

Comment: Thanks for the effort for putting this together. Something similar what we have now but we have a couple of problems with it.

Comment: Might want to put those problems in the question.